# .htaccess, get parameters together?

Tags: php, .htaccess, getparameter

`/index.php?user=username` TO `/username`

AND

`/index.php?page=settings` TO `/settings`

Please help me, suggest solutions for .htaccess or PHP, would be very grateful!

Comment: Not possible. You cannot have `/abcd` going to both `/?user=abcd` and `/?page=abcd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change .htaccess code to

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?user=$1
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```